# SQL Server CE tools to modify database in network share

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-compact

I am using SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1. I am using Web Developer 2010 Express to connect to database and perform operations like creating table, modifying column etc. But we cannot connect a database in a network share which is not allowed.

I tried with the [SQL Server CE Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/104096) and [Visual Studio add-in](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) these tools allow us to access database present in network path but does not allows us to edit columns directly. It only creates script which we need to run again. So it's not a simple tool.

Is there any other tool which allows us to directly edit columns and perform all database operation for the database (`.sdf`) in network share ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rename columns in SQL Server Compact edition you must use

```
ALTER TABLE DROP column
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE ADD column
```

Comment: You will, of course, lose the data in that column when you drop it.

Comment: Well you can backup column data in some temporary table, drop column - add it and update added column from temporary table you backed up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to edit column and perform all database operation for the database (.sdf) in the network share . So is there any tool which can connect to database in network share and allow me to edit columns?

Comment: I am confused. You can aesily edit data with the Toolbox!

Comment: @ErikEJ In the "SqlCeToolbox" toolbox we can only query and we have to run it . I needed directly to edit columns and perform all database operation for the database (.sdf) in the network share

Comment: Confused what you mean by "all database operation"  - seems to cover A lot. You can Edit data with the Toolbox, just right click a table.